# WebClient Exception when copying a file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, webclient

I want to "download" a file (more like copy it from one destination to another) in an attempt to find the best method for doing this. I've got as far as trying xcopy etc. Now I'm trying WebClient. I have the code laid out below:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

        foreach (string drivePath in _destRepository.Destinations)
        {
            do
            {
                AsyncItem job = _repository.GetNextAsyncItem();
                string source = job.DownloadLocation;
                string destination = drivePath + job.Destination;
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(source), destination);
            } while (_repository.QueueCount < 1);
        }
```

AsyncItem is just a custom class holding the source and relative destination (destination with out drive location). It will then be give its drive path and then the client show DownloadFileAsync. However in the Event Completed function I get an error. InnerException tells me that the destination doesn't exist?

Well ofr course it doesn't exist yet, WebClient has to make it. This led me to believe that maybe WebClient doesn't create folder structures? Some of these files are sitting two levels deep.

What is the opinion of StackOverflow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer for above is yes the WebClient doesn't create folder structures for you. They have to be added by doing the following:

```
FileInfo dest = new FileInfo(destination);
if (!dest.Directory.Exists)
    dest.Directory.Create();
```

But secondly and most importantly WebClient doesn't support CONCURRENT I/O operations.